# Animations in JavaScript run at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newbie web developer and stackoverflow member here,

I'm currently enrolled in an Udemy web development bootcamp and I'm learning about JavaScript and jQuery. The assessment is to create the Simon game. I already finished it, but I wanted to make some changes.

In the **Simon game** there are some buttons (in my case four button of color blue, red, yellow and green) and they are randomly choosen, creating a sequence of colors. Then, the player must press the buttons following the sequence. If it's ok, a new color will be chosen and added to the existing sequence.

In the assessment, every time a level completed, only the new button is showed. Here is the difference between this and what I want to do: I want to show the complete sequence again finishing with the new color.

**What I tried:** I used a for loop to walk in to the sequence. Inside the loop, each color in the sequence would be shown one by one, and I used a setTimeOut to create a time interval between each color. Here is the code:

```js
// This function generates a new position in the gamePattern by randomly select
// a number between 0-4 and finding the correspond colour in buttonColours

function nextSequence() {

  ...some code
  for (var j=0; j<level; j++) {
    doSetTimeout(j, gamePattern);
  }
}

// This is the function that doesn't work ----------------------------
// I think the trouble is the delay function I'm using: setTimeout
// Maybe the for loop above is running this function as many times as there are
// colours in gamePattern but it doesn't wait to finish the last timeOut, and
// all setTimeOuts are running at the same time. I hope I was clear, I'm not a
// native english speaker. Sorry if I wasn't

function doSetTimeout(j, gamePattern) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    // This is the animation of the buttons in the game pattern
    $("#" + gamePattern[j]).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    playSound(gamePattern[j]);

  }, 1000);

}
```

**The trouble:** all buttons in the game sequence are shown at the same time, and I want this to occurs one by one.

Sorry if there is so much text. I only wanted to be explicit.

I uploaded the code to a GitHub repo if someone is interested in reading the code. https://github.com/jsierrabravo/simonGame

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // This is the animation of the buttons in the game pattern
    $("#" + gamePattern[j]).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    playSound(gamePattern[j]);

  }, 1000 * j);
```

The change: `1000 * j` as the timeout milliseconds variable. That will space out your buttons to not all appear at once.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I didn't think the solution was that easy.